# How can I solve problems from dual boot on MacbookPro(Ubuntu) WIFI?

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, sound, keyboard, macbook-pro

I have install on MacbookPro 2016 dual boot MacOs and Ubuntu? I havent connections on wifi,only with lan(sometimes).I try some commands that I find , but no solution.Thank you.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 
BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)      
Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:0157]
Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac  Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

.

```
[    5.007976] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac  
[    5.136826] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/2    
[    5.138755] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro13,2.txt failed with error -2    
[    5.138769] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2    
[    5.472861] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/2    
[    5.472891] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available    
[    5.473317] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43602/2 wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c    
[    5.512360] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0    
[    5.754337] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2    
[    5.754339] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
```

.

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

.

```
sudo iwlist scan

[sudo] password for vita:
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 24:58:6E:BC:E3:C7
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=17/70  Signal level=-93 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WIND_6xUapP"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B57494E445F367855617050
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A0C181FFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C330C181FFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3406000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0600E04C020160
                    IE: Unknown: DD0E0050F204104A0001101044000102
          Cell 02 - Address: 30:99:35:B4:AF:C2
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"olympiakos7"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B6F6C796D7069616B6F7337
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706475220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 46053208010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A1E181BFFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D16060D1600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400080000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180204000C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

.

```
rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: The question is too broad. Each problem like Wi-fi, audio, etc may have its own solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Let's also see: `dmesg | grep brcm` We suspect that you require but are missing firmware.

Comment: Does wlp2s0 appear in: `iwconfig`? Are there scan results or an error? `sudo iwlist scan` Is the switch set to enable wireless? `rfkill list all`

Comment: @chili555 dificult problem?

Comment: If it scans and sees networks, then it ought to connect when you click the Network Manager icon and select your network. What happens when you try?

Comment: It see the networks , but i cant join to my home network.Response message say : Authentication required by wireless network.But when I make wifi from my phone , when the macbook have connection with wifi.

Comment: Is it good to make factory settings to my router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem on MacBookPro13,2 with the wifi:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
MacBookPro13,2
```

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot, and the behavior is that although I can see 2GHz wifi network (no 5GHz), when I connect to it, it keeps asking for the password, even if it was introduced correctly.

I have the same wifi hardware:

```
lspci -nn | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:0157]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

I'm expecting `brcmfmac` driver to support `BCM43602 [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)`,

I have the same errors when `brcmfmac` driver loads:

```
sudo rmmod brcmfmac
sudo dmesg -C
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
dmesg
[  758.560640] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[  758.666665] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/2
[  758.667797] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro13,2.txt failed with error -2
[  758.667873] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[  759.006375] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/2
[  759.006446] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[  759.007055] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43602/2 wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[  759.047217] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
mrabule1@mrabule1-MacBookPro:~$
```

There are no such files in my `/lib/firmvar`e:

```
brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro13,2.txt
brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt
```

Here is what I have:

```
sudo ls /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43602*
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
```

I found various discussions forums where people said they got this hardware working.

I tried various solution on Ubuntu 16.04, which did not work, then I give up, and switched to Ubuntu 18.04, hoping it is newer and copes better with the hardware. Still does not work. I think I will try again some solutions described [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193121):

Until this works, I'm on wire connection, using a USB to eth dongle, but I would really be glad if wifi would work.

Comment: It s the last solution..I think..after the macbook wanna go for sale. :)